# Laptop does not turn off after upgrade sysytem to Ubuntu 23.10 - SOLVED!

Tags: 23.10

Ubuntu 23.10 Laptop Sony Vaio Linux 6.5.0-13-generic RAM 8,0 GiB CPU Intel® Core™ i7-2640M × 4, two GPUIntel® HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2) and  AMD TURKS.
In last version of Ubuntu everything worked fine after upgrade laptop doesn't switch off, screen is black, fan is working and on/off led is green.

`snap-store[3376]: fwupd_client_download_bytes_async: assertion 'url != NULL' failed`

`ubuntu-report[2787]: level=error msg="data were not delivered successfully to metrics server, retrying in 120s"`

such errors I found

Problem solved after last apt upgrade!
Thanks!

Comment: What method did you use to shut down? Have you tried `sudo poweroff`?

Comment: Yes, I tried 'sudo poweroff' no change, the same effect like using the top menu to switch off.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title on this question answer site. Feel free to click on the **Answer Your Own Question** button below and answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

Diagnostic procedure:

First step is to put a pin in the timestream with

```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
```

Then, do your suspend/shutdown thing. When your system is usable again,

```
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
```

This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. Some messages relate to your problem.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].